# Compare 2 Excel (or Sheet 1 and Sheet2) that has same table structure

Tags: excel

I have 2 excel files in which I have 10 same columns in both. I need to check if the rows of Excel 1 is available in Excel 2 or not.
Its is not neccessary that Row 1 of Excel 1 should match with Row 1 of Excel 2. Infact, any row of Excel 1 can be found in any row of Excel 2. Just the ordering and nomenclature of columns are sam in both excels (or may in both sheets of a single excel).

Any function or formula for this? Pleaes guide.

Comment: Make helper columns in each table and concatenate values from all columns (for better reliability you may delimit values with some symbol like "-"). Then `VLOOKUP` one table's helper column in another's.

Comment: Do you want to check *every* column in some row in Excel1 matches *every* column in some row in Excel 2

Comment: Yes Mcalex, you are right. Every column should match with every column of Excel 2.
How to do this?

Comment: Hi Taosique, I am very new to use such formulae. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: How to use VLOOKUP for two columns that are present in different sheets of same excel (A of Sheet 1 with A of Sheet 2)?
If both are in same sheet, I sue a formula like this:
NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))